# Displaying label on the bottom right corner of a table cell

Tags: c#, html, css, asp.net

I want to assign a label in the bottom right corner.

I am doing it dynamically in C# code.

```
 string css = ""; string cssDate="DateRightColumn"; string ="Main Content"
        Label l1 = new Label();
        tblCell = new HtmlTableCell();
        Panel pnl1 = new Panel();
        Panel pnlDate = new Panel();
        pnl1.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl(string.Format("<span>{0}</span>", value)));

        l1.Text = "hello"
        l1.CssClass = cssDate;
        pnl1.Controls.Add(l1);
        tblCell.Controls.Add(pnl1);

.DateRightColumn {
    bottom:0px;
    right:0px;
    font-size:8px;
    height:20px;
}
```

Here, I get the data and the l1=hello is displayed at the bottom, but not on the bottom right corner.
Can anyone help me how can I achieve this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you miss the position in your css class:

```
.DateRightColumn {
    position: absolute;
    bottom:0px;
    right:0px;
    font-size:8px;
    height:20px;
}
```

also you have to add `postion: relative` to the control where you want the label be in the right-bottom corner so I think is your HtmlTable.

Comment: I tried this, then the label disappears

Comment: try adding the position: relative if not could you post the aspx section for the HtmlTable.

Comment: Yes, I did that and it worked. But if the html content is big enough in the panel then this label and the html content collides. WHat should I do for that ?

Comment: It's difficult to say without knowing the html but maybe a margin in one side or a min-width could work

Comment: Its is like having a table cell and inside a table cell, I have a panel a label. So the content of panel and label(bottom right corner) collides.

Comment: I think you could put a margin-right in panel to avoid that collision